# Scripting in Android with terminal emulator

Tags: android, linux, shell, terminal-emulator

I was a beginner in Linux. And I had no Computer when I wrote this. I used terminal emulator on my Android to run Linux commands. I installed Busybox too. I also had root access.I tried to execute a shell script  "sample.sh". The terminal opens but the file was not executed. So I asked "What is the .bat equivalent extension in linux?".

Is this really a very bad question? What was the point in downvoting the question here? I clearly mentioned what I have tried and What happended. And that genuine downvoter never explained the reason. Is this the correct way to treat a newbie. With lots of hatred from my various questions, I lost hope and never used S.O.

So if there is still hope. Can anyone justify the actions?

Comment: S.O. members - Justify the downvote and not just downvote. We're here to educate, not to bully or, dare I say, troll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent extension is `.sh`, but you also need the correct [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line. The first line of a unix script is examined to determine the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Magic_number) - you want something like

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

And the file needs to have the executable bit set,

```
chmod a+x file.sh
```

Comment: And the executable bit, `chmod a+x file.sh`.